# How to convert row names to columns on a large number of dataframes

Tags: r

Say I have 100 dataframes, each one has identical column names but different row names. I'd like to convert the row names to the first column and name it "gene" for all 100 dataframes. Does anyone know what are efficient ways to do this?

```
df_list <- c(df1, df2, df3,..., df100)
...
???
df_list2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column("gene")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the dataframes in a list and apply `tibble::rownames_to_column` to each list.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:100))
#Or list them individually
#list_df <- dplyr::lst(df1, df2, ..., df100)
list_df <- lapply(list_df, tibble::rownames_to_column, var = 'gene')
#If you want the changes to be reflected to each dataframe
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

List the data frames.

```
L <- list(df1, df2, df3)
## or
L <- mget(ls(pattern="^df"))
```

Then use `` `names<-` `` in `Map`.

```
Map(function(x, y, z) {names(x)[y] <- z;x}, L, 1, "gene")
# [[1]]
# gene X2 X3 X4
# 1    1  4  7 10
# 2    2  5  8 11
# 3    3  6  9 12
# 
# [[2]]
# gene X2 X3 X4
# 1    1  4  7 10
# 2    2  5  8 11
# 3    3  6  9 12
# 
# [[3]]
# gene X2 X3 X4
# 1    1  4  7 10
# 2    2  5  8 11
# 3    3  6  9 12
```

that's actually cool within a function.

```
FUN <- function(x, y, z) Map(function(x, y, z) {names(x)[y] <- z;x}, x, y, z)

FUN(L, 2, "gene")
# [[1]]
# X1 gene X3 X4
# 1  1    4  7 10
# 2  2    5  8 11
# 3  3    6  9 12
# 
# [[2]]
# X1 gene X3 X4
# 1  1    4  7 10
# 2  2    5  8 11
# 3  3    6  9 12
# 
# [[3]]
# X1 gene X3 X4
# 1  1    4  7 10
# 2  2    5  8 11
# 3  3    6  9 12
```

---

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

A memory *efficient* way would be to overwrite the old dataframes.

```
for(i in ls(pattern="^df\\d+$")) {assign(i, data.frame(
 gene = rownames(get(i)), get(i), row.names = NULL))}

df1
#  gene x a
#1    T 4 2

df2
#  gene y b
#1    X 2 4
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=4, a=2, row.names = "T")
df2 <- data.frame(y=2, b=4, row.names = "X")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data.frames in a list, `mapply` can do it. It's the ideal base function since it has an argument `MoreArgs`, a named list, where you can pass the new column name value.

```
df_list <- list(mtcars, iris, ChickWeight)

mapply(tibble::rownames_to_column, df_list, MoreArgs = list(var = "gene"))
```